# How to fix TaskCancelledException due to timeout?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am developping an API that will be the link between my website and the database. For developement purposes (won't be available in production), I am creating a database controller that I can use to drop and recreate my database.

This is the problematic code, that I took [here](https://makolyte.com/ef-core-apply-migrations-programmatically/) :

```
public async void CreateDatabaseAndTables()
{
    // When not specifying a migration name in MigrateAsync, the method calls the last migration executed
    await this._instituteDbContext.GetInfrastructure().GetService<IMigrator>().MigrateAsync();
}
```

When I first executed it, I had a TaskCancelledException. After investigating, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179848/httpclient-a-task-was-cancelled). I then checked my exception and from there I was able to find out that the task is cancelled (probably) due to a timeout.

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70615783/change-dotnet-6-inbound-request-timeout), I tried to set a new timeout :

```
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
});
```

But it didn't fix my issue.

So I am wondering if there is another solution to this or if I have to investigate somewhere else to find the cause of the issue, if it's not due to a timeout exceeded ?

```
Unhandled exception. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func 4 operation, Func 4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.ExistsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.GetAppliedMigrationsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetAppliedMigrationsAsync(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Infrastructure.SqlServer.System.DatabaseManager.CreateDatabaseAndTables() in D:\Progra\CSharp\Privé\InstitutServeur\Infrastructure\SqlServer\System\DatabaseManager.cs:line 32
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.<>c.<.cctor>b__6_0(QueueUserWorkItemCallback quwi)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunForThreadPoolUnsafe[TState](ExecutionContext executionContext, Action`1 callback, TState& state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
```

EDIT :
I tried to fix the issue by changing my mistake (writing "void" instead of "Task"). But I still have the same issue, and even further investigation didn't help me.

I wrote this in the method (which goal is to drop and recreate the database), but it gives the same exception of cancelled Task :

```
await this._instituteDbContext.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
await this._instituteDbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
await this._instituteDbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
```

I can't find why does my app cancels this Task, and I have, atm, no more info to give about the exception.

Comment: That `async void` is really suspicious. Why not `Task`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kestrel timeout has nothing to do with the timeout for EF Core database calls. You can change that either during the context registration:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(builder => 
    builder.UseSqlite($"Filename={nameof(SomeContext)}.db", opts => opts.CommandTimeout(3600)));
```

Or for concrete context instance:

```cs
ctx.Database.SetCommandTimeout(3600); // possibly will require restoration in some cases
```

Still I would recommend investigating what is causing the timeout - EF Core allows to generate migration SQL script and you can use it to either apply migration manually or see what is wrong.

Also you should avoid `async void` methods, change `CreateDatabaseAndTables` signature to:

```cs
public async Task CreateDatabaseAndTables()
```

Comment: I will continue investigating on this, none of the options you presented worked, the task still get cancelled. I will update you if I find something.

Comment: @Scryper you might want to change `public async void CreateDatabaseAndTables()` to `public async Task CreateDatabaseAndTables()` also.

Comment: I answered too fast, I still get the task cancelled. At first I thought it was fixed, but then when trying to reset my db, I saw that it had no effect. I then reran the project in debug mode, and saw I was still getting the same exception.